# How to connect using specific network adapter?

Tags: delphi, network-programming

We are using Delphi Berlin 10.2

We have an application that runs on devices with 2 or more ethernet adapters.  It's mandatory for us to choose a specific network adapter.

I researched and failed to find a way to do this using Indy, Synapse, or even Winsock.

The connect methods don't offer this option, they offer only destination IP and port.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You need to `bind()` the client socket to the local IP address of the desired network interface, then `connect()` will reach out to the server's IP:port using the network that the interface is attached to.

Indy has properties for that purpose, for instance the `BoundIP` property of `TIdTCPClient`.

I'm sure Synapse (and most other networking libraries) has its own equivalent for this, too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Sorry, maybe i wasn't clear in my explanation...

The fact is that we have an application that runs on a device that has two network adapters.

The destination IP (which is placed in the BoundIP property to connect) is define, then is not a problem.
The question is how to choose which
of these physical interfaces the communication will be carried out.
Is there a solution to define the physical network output interface?
Thanks.

Comment: @GabrielM.T. the `BoundIP` is meant for the *local* IP of the desired network that the client wants to use. The `Host` is meant for the *destination* hostname/IP. Every network interface has its own IP address. So bind your client to the local IP of the desired interface, and then `connect` to the desired server `Host`.

Comment: Remy, thanks for your reply! Sorry for my mistake with BoundIP definition. One last doubt: If these two network interfaces have the same IP, it's possible to identify? In my solution, this situation (same IP) is possible, because one of these interfaces will be conected to a customer LAN, with DHCP, and the other with fixed IP, on my proprietary network. See the schema below: https://imgur.com/a/0Sv3pVZ

Comment: @GabrielM.T. If multiple interfaces have the same IP address, there is no way to differentiate between them for purposes of binding, at least on Windows, as it can bind only by IP. On Posix platforms, an interface can also be bound to by its name or index instead of IP. Indy doesn't implement support for that at this time, however try using the client's `OnSocketAllocated`or `OnAfterBind` event to make the relevant Posix API calls manually. But, you really should strive to ensure your "proprietary" network uses IPs that are different from other networks. It should be on a different subnet.